# Alpha parameter in model-based recursive partitioning: unexpected results

Tags: r, regression, party

I have the following code using R `partykit` package, which yields unexpected results.

```r
library(partykit)
library(palmtree)
data("BostonHousing", package="mlbench")
set.seed(123)
BostonSample <- BostonHousing[sample(nrow(BostonHousing), 150), ]
lmtree(medv ~ lstat + ptratio + tax | ptratio + tax, data=BostonSample)
```

The results are as expected to this point, however:

```
library(palmtree)
palmtree(medv ~ lstat | ptratio + tax | ptratio + tax, data=BostonSample)
```

Results in a tree with only one node, a bit surprising. Let's try to raise alpha parameter and see what happens:

```
tree <- palmtree(medv ~ lstat | ptratio + tax | ptratio + tax, data=BostonSample, alpha=0.2)
plot(tree)
```

Now this results in a tree which has first split with `p = 0.004`. A bit confusing, since the first PALM tree didn't include split with the default alpha (0.05). What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this is surprising. However, this is caused by iterating between the estimation of

- the groups from the tree *given* the global additive fixed effects from the linear model
- the global additive fixed effects from the linear model *given* the groups from the tree

By default, the iteration is initialized with a one-group model, in your example `medv ~ lstat + ptratio + tax`. The residuals from this have no significant in the `lstat` slope with respect to the `ptratio` and `tax` split variables at 5% level. Hence, the algorithm stops here.

If you use a 20% level instead, the following happens:

- A single split in `tax` is found with p = 0.149.
- Then, the linear model is updated, using two separate intercepts and `lstat` slopes for `tax` <= 281 and `tax` > 281.
- This changes the global fixed effect coefficients of `ptratio` and `tax`.
- With the modified fixed effects as offsets, the `lmtree` finds the same split in `tax` as above but now with p = 0.004.
- As the full model is the same as before (because the split point did not change), the iteration stops.

In short, given a single group, the global additive coefficients of `ptratio` and `tax` are such that no split is found at 5% level. But given two groups, the global additive coefficients are such that the same split is found again at 5% level.

Possibly, this kind of "local optimum" situation is facilitated by using the same variables as global linear regressors and splitting variables. But I guess it can also occur in other situations.

If you want to track the evolution of the model over the iterations you can also do:

```
par(ask = TRUE)
palmtree(medv ~ lstat | ptratio + tax | ptratio + tax, data=BostonSample,
  alpha = 0.2, plot = TRUE, verbose = TRUE)
```

This prints the fitted log-likelihood and plots the `lmtree` from the intermediate steps.